# Google-assistant integration dialog flow: List not working in google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am sending both simple_response and list_card in messages to dialog flow but google assistant stops responding

After response from webhook my json in dialog flow looks like:

```
{
  "id": "c8d70d1a-fe39-4417-94a8-f586db516961",
  "timestamp": "2017-12-04T09:40:11.687Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Popular Science",
    "action": "searchWithCategory",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "any": "Popular Science"
    },
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "filter",
        "parameters": {
          "item": "library",
          "any.original": "Popular Science",
          "any": "Popular Science"
        },
        "lifespan": 5
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "12a29272-a89d-4fae-b4f8-497f75f6f1d1",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 331,
      "intentName": "searchStoriesWithCategory"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "We have found 2 articles for you",
      "source": "webhook",
      "displayText": "We have found 2 articles for you",
      "messages": [
        {
          "speech": "We have found 2 articles for you",
          "type": 0
        },
        {
          "textToSpeech": "We have found 2 articles for you",
          "type": "simple_response",
          "platform": "google"
        },
        {
          "title": "We have found 2 articles for you",
          "type": "list_card",
          "items": [
            {
              "image": {
                "url": "http://image1.example.png"
              },
              "optionInfo": {
                "synonyms": [
                  "P"
                ],
                "key": "PubMed: Swine Flu"
              },
              "description": "PubMed: Swine Flu",
              "title": "PubMed: Swine Flu"
            },
            {
              "image": {
                "url": "http://image1.example.png"
              },
              "optionInfo": {
                "synonyms": [
                  "L"
                ],
                "key": "Local Level - Resolving community Issues"
              },
              "description": "Local Level - Resolving community Issues",
              "title": "Local Level - Resolving community Issues"
            }
          ],
          "platform": "google"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "002e6053-78c1-49ee-a9dc-76df21fac798"
}
```

Comment: Exactly where is this JSON coming from? The simulator Debug tab, or somewhere else?

Comment: JSON is coming from dialogflow show json tab after the webhook response